# Remove empty lists in Scala from ArrayType column in Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a column in dataframe which is of type ArrayType. For now in this column, I have empty lists.
Eg:

```
+-------+
|xyz|
+-------+
|[a,,]  |
|[]     |
+-------+
```

I want to remove the null values from the list and output the column as :

```
+-------+
|xyz|
+-------+
|[a]    |     
+-------+
```

How can I achieve this while joining this column? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` and `filter` to achieve this.

```scala
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

val data = Seq(Array("a",null,""), Array(""))
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
val df = rdd.toDF("xyz")
df.show() 

+------+
|   xyz|
+------+
|[a,, ]|
|    []|
+------+


// Use map to filter out all the null or empty strings, then remove rows that are empty arrays
val mappedDF = df
  .map{case Row(x:WrappedArray[String]) => x
    .filter(_ != null)
    .filter(_.nonEmpty)
  }
  .toDF("xyz")
  .filter(size(col("xyz")) > 0)
mappedDF.show()

+---+
|xyz|
+---+
|[a]|
+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{size, col, expr}

df.withColumn("xyz", expr("filter(xyz, x -> x is not null)"))
  .filter(size(col("xyz")) > 0)
```